# How would someone go about proving every known fact about the universe?

Tags: logic

I will tell my wife known facts about the universe, and she will then tell me “well that could be fake how do we really know”. Even after explaining all the telescopes and other tools we have to find these facts. She still denies them.

Comment: Even taking a program of study for a scientific degree at a university would not cover "proving every known fact". So how much time do you have to spend on it? And presenting scientific proofs never stopped people from denying facts they dislike.

Comment: According to eternal inflation, it's more likely that I'm a Boltzmann brain than that the universe exists. So good luck proving anything at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_brain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_inflation

Comment: Currently we're not sure we've ever invented a solid set-theoretic model (such as a true model of ZFC set theory for most math areas) for a continuous line which means we're not sure we can even describe all known facts about the universe (including mind), not even prove all them...

Answer (score 0):

A belief in logic is one thing and a belief in empirical data is another. All common natural sciences are deductive systems, so if you believe in classical logic, you can't deny their reasoning. But you can always deny someone's claim that he/she did such and such experiment and observed such and such data.

I mean the notion of belief is needed for the acceptance of pretty much EVERY damn system our civilization commonly applies, be it a religion or a logic. That's a philosophical argument. From a logical standpoint: there's not much you can do about someone's denial of EVERYTHING.

Comment: In pure logic realm, there was a famous argument against some skepticism schools believing in "denial (non-acceptance) of everything" doctrine. Then some other schools of thought asked them "do u accept your own "non-acceptance of everything" belief? If they accept, it means they still accept something, thus their belief is not perfect in all cases. If they don't accept, it means they're in conflict with their own doctrine. So I think we can use logic at least to show people you have to specifically believe something, not blindly reject or accept everything uncritically...

Comment: That's an interesting comment. But I don't think assigning a logical value to some statement (which your denial/acceptance of a doctrine is) enforces one to act/not to act according to this statement in real life. Tarski's resolution to the liar paradox comes to mind, namely the postulate to assign logical values to a language's statements in a meta-language.

Comment: For me, any logical value true or false attached to a statemen can always be mapped to an equivalent existence statement with clear axiomatic definitions (duality principle). If my extreme skepticism doctrine above mapped to a rough claim there exists such a doctrine which rejects all doctrines, immediately u'll find it's not enough, u have to include one's conscious action to accept or reject into the whole story. So in summary pure logician's endeavor to judge true of false is not the complete truth, it's just a part of it, one's conscious action is also a part of it.

Comment: Then we'll realize some truth must contain an active vis-viva consciousness part, then there'll be no more paradox. If one acts to accept such a doctrine, clearly she's not adhering to it literally, but her intention is actually inline with the doctrine's semantic meaning. If she rejects, she's adhering to it literally, but such action effectively despises the doctrine's meaning. So this doctrine essentially makes people schizophrenia, thus it's not a sensibly good doctrine. This way we can convince people avoid this doctrine. Similarly for Liar Paradox, we can convince people not to lie.

Comment: You know that the Liar Paradox is not about lying, but about self-reference of statements, right? I don't exactly follow your train of thought here..

Comment: Yes I know the thousands years old Liar Paradox is heavily studied in philosophical logic as a nominal paradox, and many scholars proposed ways to remedy it such as Tarski. I just proposed my way to try to convince people reject this extreme skepticism doctrine which rejects Everything on a semantic stance, since you expressed pessimism about this in your reply based on purely logic standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For all but the most basic claims is no type of demonstration which can overcome *every* level of skepticism. For example, all physical evidence whatsoever can immediately be thrown out by the question "But how do we know we aren't just brains in a vat?" The ultra-skeptic is playing a largely unloseable game.

This, however, does not in principle mean that all is lost. One issue is that, unless the ultra-skeptic wants to remove themself from all decision-making processes (including e.g. voting), they must have some notion of "convinced *enough to take a stance*." This takes us into the realm of **relative confidence** claims, where there is much more to be said ("Yes it's possible that ~A, but that would require B; since B is really really unlikely, *even though* I'm not certain A is true I'll still take the stance that A is true, rather than that A is false, when it comes to decisions depending on A").

Of course, the above implicitly distinguishes between a "principled ultra-skeptic" and a conspiracy theorist. Someone who invokes ultra-skepticism purely to preserve their existing opinion against all evidence is, to put it mildly, difficult to reason with *(and in my experience is sadly more common than the principled ultra-skeptic)*. At this point I think the focus needs to shift from philosohpy-of-argumentation to psychology: the conspiracy-theoretic *mindset* needs to be addressed before any forward progress can be made. While there is a lot written on this topic, since I'm not familiar with it I'll end my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

In philosophy, at least for your most fundamental satisfaction, there're generally 2 ways to try to make sense of every known fact about the universe: infinitism and foundationalism. With infinitism, you basically can investigate cause-effect diligently to such an extent that you'll need to regress to an infinite chain of efficient causes (dharma) within this sensible physical world, like the ancient Indra's Net told in Eastern religions. Or with foundationalism, you can claim certain axioms as your logical foundation, much same as a scientist, to try to deduce or explain all other facts based on your finite axioms.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

Your wife isn't wrong.

It is impossible to prove anything *ex nihilo*, without the belief in assuptions which -although justified, justifiable or  even very plausible- cannot be proven (scientifically).
There is no way of knowing **absolutely** that **Descartes' Evil Demon** isn't constantly fooling us all.
Now, one could find this idea ridiculous, frightening, or worthless. I disagree. I find it rather enthralling and I do not think that it denies our knowledge or negates the value of science.
From my point of view, this idea brings a healthy dose of skepticism and humilty, which history has shown to be crucial to the scientific endeavour.

Besides, **I would say that philosophy is born from this very contemplation of the dialectical confrontation between this potential nothingness and our quest for positive knowledge.** (I would  advise you to watch this lecture by Alain Badiou, "*Beyond Positivsm and Nihilism*" on this topic. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_kvL1Sg6ms)

Answer (score 0):

You do it by keeping your sights on the end goal. You want to see the big picture, and you assemble it as a jigsaw puzzle, individual facts being the puzzle pieces.

As you can imagine, with the puzzle this big, there is only one way you can piece it up correctly. In fact, when you have enough of the territory covered, you wouldn't even need to discover a particular piece to know what you will see in that spot. For example, I started referencing pre-historic "warlessness" well before I saw the term and the archeological evidence behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not a philosophy problem but a motive problem, and I think you already know that. The solution ultimately is to address her motives and feelings, because there is no way to prove anything without relying on some assumptions. One possible way to start is to ask her to convince you that she exists and is not merely a figment of your imagination, and employ the same kind of evidence that she employs to convince you. There is nothing better than getting people to actually start thinking about the kind of evidence they would believe in.